# Ruby link helper using the routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hyperlink

Okay so I know this is very basic but I have searched everywhere and I cannot find a solution.
This is my routes file:

```
match '/interestonly' => 'interestonlymortgagecalculators#interestonlymortgagecalculator'
```

How do I create the link to link to this? I taught it would be as simple as

```
<%= link_to 'Interest Only Mortgage Calculator',  interestonly %>
```

Can someone please help me I know this is very basic stuff but I can;t find anything on it, possibly due to my wording of the question

Comment: Try `interestonly_path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to read this over: [Ruby on Rails Guides: Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls). I've linked directly to the relevant section.

What you want is the path helper, which you can access by running `rake routes` in the command line. The path helper will be in the left column. After your comma in the code above, you should type in the path helper.